# UITextField Keyboard Closes after every key tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, collectionview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have looked at other answers and so far none have been helpful. The keyboard to my UITextField collapses after every key tap. I am not sure what is causing it. I have an extension which alerts when the keyboard is being shown but that works in other projects I have created as well.

Below is the code in its entirety

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,printDelegateWorkedDelegate{


    func printDelegateWorkedDelegate() {
        print("The delegate worked")
    }

    var genericTagsArray:[String] = ["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","tag8","tag9","tag10","tag11","tag12","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Ab","Abc","za","tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","tag8","tag9","tag10","tag11","tag12","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Ab","Abc","za"]
    var currentTagsArray:[String] = [String]()
    var tagsSelected:[String] = [String]()
    let keyboardSlider = KeyboardSlider()

    var header:feedViewHeader = feedViewHeader()

    @IBOutlet weak var feedScreenCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        keyboardSlider.subscribeToKeyboardNotifications(view: view)
        currentTagsArray = genericTagsArray

        let viewTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(feedViewHeader.viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
        viewTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.feedScreenCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapGestureRecognizer)

        feedScreenCollectionView.delegate = self
        feedScreenCollectionView.dataSource = self

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 1, bottom: 0, right: 1)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 75)

        layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
        feedScreenCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        header.VC = self
        header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "feedViewHeader", for: indexPath) as! feedViewHeader

        return header
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentTagsArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "feedViewCell", for: indexPath) as! feedViewCell

        cell.feedImageView.backgroundColor = .blue
        cell.feedImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.feedImageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat((cell.feedImageView.frame.width)/5)
        cell.feedLabel.text = currentTagsArray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/4.0
        let collectionViewHeight = collectionViewWidth

        return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth-4, height: collectionViewHeight+25)
    }

    var lastContentOffset:CGFloat = 0

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {


        if self.lastContentOffset > self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y && self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y > 0 && self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y < self.feedScreenCollectionView.frame.maxY {
            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            header.isHidden = false
        }
        else if (self.lastContentOffset < self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y) && (self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y < self.feedScreenCollectionView.frame.maxY) && (self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y > 0)  {
            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            header.isHidden = true
        }
        else{
            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

        }


    }



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardFrameChangeNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    var offsetY:CGFloat = 0

    @objc func keyboardFrameChangeNotification(notification: Notification) {

    }


}


class feedViewCell:UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var feedImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var feedLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        feedLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        feedImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        feedImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.feedLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true

        feedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        feedLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        feedLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.feedImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        feedLabel.textAlignment = .center

    }

}

//should it be done with protocol we will have to reassess
protocol HideHeaderScrollViewDelegate {
    func hideHeaderView(hide: Bool)
}

protocol printDelegateWorkedDelegate {
    func printDelegateWorkedDelegate()
}

class feedViewHeader:UICollectionReusableView,UITextFieldDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var feedSearchBar: UITextField!

    var delegateWorked:printDelegateWorkedDelegate?

    var VC:ViewController!
    var collectionView:UICollectionView?
    var stringToBeSet = "String to be set"
//
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        print("Im in awakeFromNib in header")

        feedSearchBar.delegate = self
        feedSearchBar.autocorrectionType = .no
        feedSearchBar.keyboardType = .default
        feedSearchBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(feedViewHeader.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        self.feedSearchBar.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        self.feedSearchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.feedSearchBar.layer.borderWidth = 4
        var searchBarHeight = self.feedSearchBar.bounds.height
        self.feedSearchBar.rightViewMode = .always
    }


    @objc func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){

        if  feedSearchBar.isFirstResponder{
            feedSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

//
//
//    //Text Field Delegate
   func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()
        return true
    }

    /// Helper to dismiss keyboard
    @objc func didStopEditing() {
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.easeInOut)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.VC.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }
////
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(){
        guard(!(feedSearchBar.text?.isEmpty)!) else{
            VC.currentTagsArray = VC.genericTagsArray
            VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()
            return
        }

        VC.currentTagsArray = VC.genericTagsArray.filter({letter -> Bool in
            if feedSearchBar.text!.count > letter.count{
                return false
            }
            let stringRange = letter.index(letter.startIndex, offsetBy: feedSearchBar.text!.count)
            let subword = letter[..<stringRange]
            return subword.lowercased().contains(feedSearchBar.text!.lowercased())
        })

        if VC.currentTagsArray.isEmpty{
            VC.currentTagsArray.insert(feedSearchBar.text!, at: 0)
        }

        VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()
   }


}

extension Notification.Name{
    static let showKeyboard = Notification.Name("showKeyboard")
}
class KeyboardSlider: NSObject {
    // variables to hold and process information from the view using this class
    weak var view: UIView?

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        // method to move keyboard up
        // view?.frame.origin.y = 0 - getKeyboardHeight(notification as Notification)
        print("made it to keyboard will show")
    }

    func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) -> CGFloat {
        // get exact height of keyboard on all devices and convert to float value to return for use
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
    }

    func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications(view: UIView) {
        // assigning view to class' counterpart
        self.view = view
        // when UIKeyboardWillShow do keyboardWillShow function
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    }

    func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try commenting this line `VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()` in `@objc func textFieldDidChange()` and running it again.

Comment: Exactly, collection view reloading is causing the keyboard to close.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Thank you so much for your help and for your prompt response. I tried commenting out this line containing `VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()` and while it fixes the keyboard closing it doesnt allow the collectionView to dynamically update at the end of the users input is there a way to make both possible thank you again

Comment: Just move the updation logic to `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` ? Because the data is not final until the textField is dismissed which you will do before moving on to some other operation.

Comment: @LOKESHKUMARPEDDA Thank you as well for your response I appreciate your help, unfortunately while this does resolve the keyboard problem it doesn't allow the collectionView to dynamically update the cells as the user types.Is there any way to achieve both? Thank you for your all of your help in advance.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Thank you for your prompt response but putting the `VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()` requires the user to hit the enter button before the collectionView is updated is it possible to update the collectionView as the user is typing their characters in the `UITextField`? Thank you again.

Comment: You can use delegation to maintain an instance of the cell and update the label from the cell in `@objc func textFieldDidChange()`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Thank you for responding,, how would you keep track of which cells to update?